# How to convert a string into an Array of JScript Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, jscript, ecmascript-3

In Javascript, I have a string that I need to convert to an Array of objects.

```
//ORIGINAL STRING :
var originalString = "[13, "2017-05-22 17:02:56", "Text111"], [25, "2017-05-22 17:03:03", "Text222"], [89, "2017-05-22 17:03:14","Text333"]";
```

I need to be able to loop through each object, and get the 3 properties by using indexes.
That would give (for the first Array) :

```
myItem[0] => 13
myItem[1] => "2017-05-22 17:02:56"
myItem[2] => "Text111"
```

That first sounded simple to my head (and probably is), but after several attempts, I am still stuck.

Please note that **I cannot use jQuery** because running with a very old Javascript specification : **"Microsoft JScript"**, which is EcmaScript 3 compliant.

I thank you ;)

Comment: Your `originalString` code will throw errors due to invalid JS syntax. Are you missing quote escaping?

Comment: You could always `eval` it. Why are you using such an old version anyway? If you updated to at least 5.1 then you could use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliev : Yes, the `originalString` contains `"`, and this is not correct. The fact is that this string is returned AS IS by an external API (such a shame).
@Andrew Li : I CAN use JSON.parse (I have implemented a JS port of it, and it is fully functional).

Comment: Why would you implement `JSON.parse()` yourself rather than including the original [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) that Mr Crockford implemented years ago?

Comment: @nnnnnn The port of JSON.parse I am talking about IS the one by Crockford ;-) (json2.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just could use `JSON.parse`, then you would be able to append `[` and `]` to the beginning and ending of a string respectively, and then parse it as an array of arrays.

```js
var originalString = '[13, "2017-05-22 17:02:56", "Text111"], [25, "2017-05-22 17:03:03", "Text222"], [89, "2017-05-22 17:03:14","Text333"]';

var result = JSON.parse("[" + originalString + "]");
console.log(result);
```

However, as far as I know, `JSON.parse` is not ECMAScript 3 complaint, so you will have to parse it yourself.
Something like this should help:

```js
var originalString = '[13, "2017-05-22 17:02:56", "Text111"], [25, "2017-05-22 17:03:03", "Text222"], [89, "2017-05-22 17:03:14","Text333"]';

function trimString(str, trims) {
  var left = 0;
  var right = str.length - 1;
  
  while (left < right && trims.indexOf(str[left]) != -1) {
    left++;
  }
   
  while (left < right && trims.indexOf(str[right]) != -1) { 
    right--;
  }
  
  return str.substr(left, right - left + 1);
}

function splitByCommasOutOfBrackets(str) {
  var result = [];
  var current = "";
  var bracketBalance = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
  {
    switch (str[i]) {
      case '[':
        current = current + str[i];
        bracketBalance++;
        break;
        
      case ']':
        current = current + str[i];
        bracketBalance--;
        break; 
        
      case ',':
        if (bracketBalance === 0) {
          result.push(trimString(current, [" ", "[", "]", "\""]));
          current = "";
        } else {
          current = current + str[i];
        }
        break;  
        
      default:
        current = current + str[i];
        break;
    }
  }
  
  if (current.length > 0) {
    result.push(trimString(current, [" ", "[", "]", "\""]));
  }
  
  return result;
}

var arr = splitByCommasOutOfBrackets(originalString);
console.log("1: Split by commas which separate arrays");
console.log(arr);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = splitByCommasOutOfBrackets(arr[i]);
}

console.log("2: Split every array by the same rules");
console.log(arr);
```

I am not quite sure what functionality exists in ECMAScript 3 and I used MDN for this. It looks like many functions even like [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) do not exist in ECMAScript 3. So I had to reimplement it myself. If I am wrong and you can use them in JScript, then just use some of these functions instead.

The general idea of algorithm is the following:

1. Split string by commas **out of** brackets, i.e. commas which separate our *arrays*. And then trim each string whitespaces, brackets, quotes - all these things that we don't need. As the result, we have an array of strings, each of them represents an *array*.
2. Then apply the same rule for every *array*, separating it to values.

Note that all values are threaded as strings in this solution.

It could be rewritten in a recursive way instead of looping if you have more nested levels, but it would be less understandable - I just have provided a minimal solution which works :) I am sure you can improve it in many ways.

Comment: Thank you for this great base !
I went with a similar approach, but not pushed as much as you did.
Dealing with the start and end of lines is a difficult part, I know...especially with the variants of [", with sometimes many spaces before and after..

Comment: This works with only your first block of code, beacause JSON.parse() is implemented with the use of the Crockford library (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do

```js
var regex = /\[([^\]]+)/g;
var originalString = '[13, "2017-05-22 17:02:56", "Text111"], [25, "2017-05-22 17:03:03", "Text222"], [89, "2017-05-22 17:03:14","Text333"]';
var result = regex.exec(originalString);
var container = [];
for (var j = 0; result ? true : false; j++) {
  var tokens= result[1].split(',');
  var tempContainer = []
  for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    tempContainer[i] = tokens[i].replace(/["\s]/g, '');
  }
  container[j] = tempContainer;
  // continue the search
  result = regex.exec(originalString);
}
console.log(container);
```

Comment: This solution is BRILLIANT ! But infortunately, EcmaScript 3 does not support the .push() method neither the .trim() method :(

Comment: Thank you for your edit ! I have marked Yeldar Kurmangaliyev as the best answer because it is the sortest, but I gave you an Upvote for the Regex approach I really like ! Thank you Dummy